# which one take long execution time for loop or multi thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, pthreads

if both loop and multi threaded are executing the same operation 
which one will take longest time ?

in my program the execution time of the multi thread is longest
in c lang

This is my program one function for the thread and the other for for loop

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

int ** A;
int ** B;
int ** C;
int ** D;

int k;
int r ;

clock_t begin_1, end_1, begin_2, end_2;
double time_spent_1, time_spent_2;


struct arguments{
int i;
int j;
   int n;
};

void initialize(){

A = (int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int *));
int i;
for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    A[i] = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));

B = (int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    B[i] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));

    C = (int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    C[i] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));

    D = (int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    D[i] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));


   }

 void generate(){

 int i,j;

 for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    for (j=0; j<2; j++){
        r = rand()%100;
        A[i][j]=r;
    }

for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    for (j=0; j<2; j++){
        r = rand()%100;
        B[i][j]=r;
    }
   }

 void mutip_1()
 {
  int i,j,temp,k;

begin_1 = clock();

for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    for (j=0; j<2; j++){
        temp = A[i][j];
        for(k=0;k<2;k++){
            C[i][k]+=temp*B[j][k];
        }
    }
  }

  end_1 = clock();

}

void* mul_mat(void* args)
{
struct arguments * temp = (struct arguments*) args;
int i = temp->i;
int j = temp->j;
int n = temp->n;

pthread_detach(pthread_self());

free(temp);

int k;

for(k=0;k<2;k++){
   D[i][k]+=n*B[j][k];
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){

initialize();
generate();
mutip_1();

pthread_t* tid = (pthread_t*)malloc((2*2)*sizeof(pthread_t)); malloc((2*2)*sizeof(pthread_t));

int i, j,k=0;
int n;

begin_2 = clock();

for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
        n=A[i][j];
        struct arguments *args=(struct arguments*)malloc((2*2)*sizeof(struct arguments));
        args->i = i;
        args->j = j;
        args->n=n;
        if (pthread_create(&tid[k++], NULL, (void*)mul_mat, (void*)args)){
            perror("Thread Problem");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
end_2 = clock();

time_spent_1 = (double)(end_1 - begin_1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
time_spent_2 = (double)(end_2 - begin_2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Matrix A: \n");
 for (i=0; i<2; i++){
 for (j=0; j<2; j++)
 printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
 printf("\n");
 }

 printf("Matrix B: \n");
 for (i=0; i<2; i++){
 for (j=0; j<2; j++)
 printf("%d ", B[i][j]);
 printf("\n");
 }

 printf("multiplication using loop: \n");
 for (i=0; i<2; i++){
 for (j=0; j<2; j++)
 printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
 printf("\n");
 }
printf("multiplication using thread: \n");
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    for (j=0; j<2; j++)
        printf("%d ", D[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}

printf("First time using loop %f \n", time_spent_1);
printf("second time using thread %f \n", time_spent_2);

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Comment: if i used in my program for loop to calculate 2 matrices multiplication, then i used multi threads to do the same operation, the time of the loop will be longer than time of thread ?

Comment: It depends on if the algorithm can be written to take advantage of [parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) and if the positive effects of parallelism exceed the [small] cost of using threads.

Comment: @alk , i already test it and the longest time was for the thread , i post this Q to know if its right or there is something wrong :)

Comment: @pst i just edit the Q & added my program code , does it work in parallel or currently?

Comment: Benchmark it - that's the only way to know what advantages uses threads brings. Just make sure the parallel code doesn't introduce concurrency bugs.

Comment: @pst and for concurrent thread only ,, which should be faster multi threads or loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Between I

```
for i=1 to 50 
   do something
next i
```

and II

```
for i=1 to 50 
   create thread that does the same something
next i
```

provided that the II calculation can run in parallel, the theoretical result is

- if threads can run on several CPUs/cores (which are free), II should be faster
- if threads run on same CPU (core), I should be slightly faster to due thread management overhead

Comment: This is only a small part of the picture. For instance, for short operations (CPUs can process millions of OPs/second), the overhead of creating a new thread can outweigh any benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Thread creation and/or issuing task to thread pool has considerable overhead due to system calls and inter-thread comms, so, on a multicore CPU:

Dimension of matrix = 2, loops in one thread faster.

Dimension of matrix = 2000000, loops in multiple threads faster.

Summary: don't thread off trivial CPU-intensive operations.